# How to display dynamic control within component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I am trying to build a custom component that renders its html control based on an input property. Where I am getting stuck is making sure all the directives on the custom component are added to the corresponding html control. Maybe I am building this wrong? Any insight would be great.

```
<custom-attribute [type]="'dropdown'" [style.display]="'block'" [(ngModel)]="message">

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-attribute',
  template: 
    `
    <input type="text" *ngIf="type === 'text'">
    <select *ngIf="type === 'dropdown'">
    `
})
export class CustomAttribute {
  @Input("type") type: string;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. What's the problem here?

Comment: two way binding for example does not work. the ngModel directive is placed on the custom-attribute not the input control.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<custom-attribute [type]="'dropdown'" [style.display]="'block'" [(message)]="message">

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-attribute',
    template: 
    `
        <input [(ngModel)]="message" type="text" *ngIf="type === 'text'">
        <select *ngIf="type === 'dropdown'">
    `
     })

    export class CustomAttribute {
      @Input("type") type: string;
      @Input('message') model:any;
    }
```

Comment: bindings are not working. the input control is empty

Comment: seems you got around it by just passing an object. two way binding will not work if you use primitive types.

Comment: Yes you are right. Two way binding works (as i know) only with object.